# Blending effect on textures

Tags: animation, libgdx

Hi i am trying to build screen animation like flickering, interlace, color separation similar to old style malfunctioning Amiga screens. The intended effects are shown in this  [video](http://vimeo.com/41880063). I am using libgdx and I already discovered the universal tween engine, which helps a lot to build transitional animations, but how should I approach those blending effects, any suggestions? I will specify my question once I learned more about libgdx, but maybe you could give me some hints already. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a clue, but would love to know an answer. I guess you could duplicate the whole screen or parts of it in a FrameBuffer and apply color/scale transformations on it.